# VHDL compiler giving me syntax error at end of entity definition

Tags: vhdl

The entity was created by the IDE and seemingly randomly started giving me a syntax error. I tried restarting IDE since that works sometimes, didn't work this time.
The compiler says `Syntax error near "end"`. The problem line is `end design1;`

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity design1 is
    Port ( Reg_A : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
           Reg_B : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
           Op_Sel : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
           C_In : in STD_LOGIC;
           C_Out : out STD_LOGIC;
           ALU_Out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
end design1;

architecture Behavioral of design1 is
begin

process is
begin
    if(Op_Sel(3) = '0') then
        if(Op_Sel(2) = '0') then --performing arithmetic
            if(Op_Sel(1 downto 0) = "00") then --transfer A
            elsif(Op_Sel(1 downto 0) = "01") then --increment A
            elsif(Op_Sel(1 downto 0) = "10") then --decrement A
            elsif(Op_Sel(1 downto 0) = "11") then --add
            end if;
        end if;
        elsif(Op_Sel(2) = '1') then --performing logic operations
            if(Op_Sel(1 downto 0) = "00") then --Not A
            if(Op_Sel(1 downto 0) = "01") then --A and B
            if(Op_Sel(1 downto 0) = "10") then --A or B
            if(Op_Sel(1 downto 0) = "11") then --A xor B
    elsif(Op_Sel(3) = '1') then --Shifting
        if(Op_Sel(2) = '0') then --right shift
        elsif(Op_Sel(2) = '1' then --left shift
        end if;
    end if;       
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Your parens aren't matched

Comment: @Mat Just noticed that I deleted a parenthesis somehow. Thanks

Comment: Secondly you are missing multiple end if statements after line 37. You are missing a closing parentheses on line 42